# Не меняется разрешение экрана

Tags: linux, ubuntu

После последнего sudo aptitude upgrade сбилось разрешение экрана. 
xrandr выдает вот что:

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        73.0*

Стоят дрова nvidia-352. Нужно как то исправлять положение, иначе меня сожрут без соли:)

uname -a:
Linux ParentPC 3.16.0-60-generic #80~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 13:37:48 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Окружение Mate

Comment: Поддержу. На моей машине было тоже самое. 14.04. Тоже Mate. Тоже после апдейта. Я полдня переставлял туда-сюда все варианты драйверов nvidia, откатывался на свободный, обновлял xorg из edgers, курил форумы... И ничего не помогло. Так что я плюнул, поставил поледнюю Xubuntu и больше не верю в LTS. Да и Mate пока сыроват.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял, что проблема в обновлении ядра, но дальше разбираться некогда, накатил систему повторно